# Keep width when using letter-spacing on hover

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, letter-spacing

I have a some basic button styles where on `:hover` I add the `letter-spacing` property:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #8065F1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-large {
  border-radius: 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 80px 0 rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.23);
  padding: 0.25rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Lorem</button>
```

Is there a way that `width` doesn't expand? Like adding `min/max-width`? However the problem is that `button` elements can contain different string length:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 80px 0 rgba($grey, 0.23);
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #8065F1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-large {
  border-radius: 32px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 80px 0 rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.23);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 80px 0 rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.23);
  padding: 0.25rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 240px;
}

.btn:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p>I need this "effect" (I added some min-width):</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Lorem</button>

<p>However it won't work for larger strings</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Lorem Ipsum</button><br><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</button>
```

I know I can use JS and append the elements fixed width to it, however I'm looking for a CSS solution - if there is one?

Comment: Maybe playing with `padding` could help

Comment: the other problem is that depending on the number of letter the width will increase a lot, how you will manage this?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yea, that's the main problem. As I said, it can be done with JS, but I was wondering if there is a CSS solution. Edit - I see what you mean, if the string is larger then only the width won't suffice. Is there a way?

Comment: @JoykalInfotech can you make an example?

Comment: i thought about it, but i realised it ain't a appropiate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On idea to approximate this is to duplicate the text considering a hidden one that has already the `letter-spacing` and another one on the top that you animate to fill the space already defined by the hidden text:

Here is an idea by making the text color the same as background:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #8065F1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-large {
  border-radius: 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 80px 0 rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.23);
  padding: 0.25rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn::before {
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
  letter-spacing: initial;
  color:#fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color:#8065F1;
  position:relative;
}
.btn:hover::before {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-text="Lorem">Lorem</button></div>

<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-text="Lorem Ipsum">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-text="Lorem Ipsum Dolor">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</button></div>
```

Another one using opacity and both pseudo element in case the background is not a solid color:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.btn-primary {
  background: linear-gradient(#8065F1,purple);
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-large {
  border-radius: 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 80px 0 rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.23);
  padding: 0.25rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn {
  position:relative;
  font-size:0;
}
.btn::before {
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
  letter-spacing: initial;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn::after {
  content:attr(data-text);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  opacity:0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.btn:hover::before {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-text="Lorem">Lorem</button></div>

<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-text="Lorem Ipsum">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-text="Lorem Ipsum Dolor">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</button></div>
```

Comment: Seems like a 'hack' but nice one - never came to mind. Funny that there is no "simpler" solution.

Comment: @Vucko I don't think there is a *simple* solution since for each letter you will increase by `xpx` thus it's something dynamic and you cannot know how much the overral `Xpx` will be but probably there is something that didn't come to my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

How about turning off **box-sizing**, then using a **percentage** for your padding? It should work well no matter what the size of your contents is, but my numbers are probably wrong so you'll need to adjust the numbers to make it accurate.

```css
    .wrapper{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    button{
        box-sizing: content-box;
        padding: 0 10.4%;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        font-size:13px;
    }
    button:hover{
        letter-spacing:0.1em;
        padding:0;
    }
    .outer-wrapper{
        
    }
```

```html
    <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button class='button'>Small Text</button>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button class='button'>Much much bigger text</button>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button class='button'>Small TextSmall TextSmall TextSmall TextSmall Text</button>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit: Well, it's...more or less working, except that it turns out to be **impossible**. No matter how finely I tune it, I'm getting problems because of differences in browser rendering of sub-pixels. (The browser apparently rounds **rem** differently than it does **%**, which means this is going to be impossible to do with pure CSS.)

Comment: @Vucko I've modified my answer.....But now I'm convinced it's impossible, because of the way the browser renders sub-pixels differently based on whether it's % or px.